# Implementing forward geocoding function inside an iOS swiftui view

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-location

So I'm trying to make an iOS app using swiftui that forward geocodes an address and then places those coordinates in variables that can be used in the rest of my views. The function I'm using for forward geocoding looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var myText = "Some Text just for reference"
    @State var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    @State var lat: Double?
    @State var long: Double?

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
        Text(myText)
                  .onAppear {
                      self.getLocation(from: "22 Sunset Ave, East Quogue, NY") { coordinates in
                          print(coordinates ?? 0) // Print here
                          self.location = coordinates // Assign to a local variable for further processing
                        self.long = coordinates?.longitude
                        self.lat = coordinates?.latitude
                      }
              }
         Text("\(long)")
         Text("\(lat)")
        }

    }
      func getLocation(from address: String, completion: @escaping (_ location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?)-> Void) {
          let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
          geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
              guard let placemarks = placemarks,
          let location = placemarks.first?.location?.coordinate else {
              completion(nil)
              return
        }
          completion(location)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

My questions are, how should I be calling this function inside of my contentview file so I can save the coordinates as variables and how do I call the function to print them to the screen just to verify the code is operating correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this within the `onAppear()` method in a very simple manner. However, I would encourage you to use a View Model to fetch the coordinates using an address.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var myText = "Some Text just for reference"
    @State var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var body: some View {
        Text(myText)
            .onAppear {
                self.getLocation(from: "Some Address") { coordinates in
                    print(coordinates) // Print here 
                    self.location = coordinates // Assign to a local variable for further processing
                }
        }
    }

    func getLocation(from address: String, completion: @escaping (_ location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?)-> Void) {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
            guard let placemarks = placemarks,
            let location = placemarks.first?.location?.coordinate else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            completion(location)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When Implementing this approach the following error is given: Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type. Also the warning: Result of call to 'onAppear(perform:)' is unused, is display. Any suggestions on how to fix these?

Comment: @TJD'Alessandro are you using the onAppear like I did in my example?

Comment: I copied this code into a brand new project and when I ran it, the errors I mentioned appeared

Comment: @TJD'Alessandro can you share your code here in the chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212370/swiftui-geocoding

Comment: I am not able to post in the chat as I have less than 20 reputation. The code in my project is exactly what you wrote in your answer

Comment: @TJD'Alessandro I am able to compile and run the above code without any issues. There might be some error in your `var body: some View`  which is giving that error. I would not be able to debug without looking at the code

Comment: That is the line where the error is. Is there any other way I could send you my code?

Comment: @TJD'Alessandro you can edit your question above to include the latest code.

Comment: I've edited the code, the error: Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type, is on line 8

Comment: You have added 2 Text Views together. You can't do that. you have to wrap them in another view. Remove line 9  `Text("Hello, World!")` and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help I really appreciate it. Could you show me how I can save the longitude and latitude in variables that could be used as coordinates in a map view

Comment: I am already doing in this line `self.location = coordinates` inside the view. You now have the reference to the location coordinates. You can access it by `self.location.longitude` and `self.location.latitude`. Please mark it as answer if it solves your problem

Comment: I've updated the code to show the problem, The text fields in the VStack with the variables lat and long give this error: Instance method 'appendInterpolation' requires that 'Double?' conform to '_FormatSpecifiable'. I'd also like to use this function not on a .onAppear method so I can call the lat and long variables throughout my code

Comment: Since both of them are nullable, you would have to provide a default value like this: 
`Text("\(long ?? 0)")` & `Text("\(lat ?? 0)")`. As far using the lat long across your code, that's beyond the scope of this question. You can follow various pattern like MVVM (most suitable), to achieve that.